# Error in scp connection in Linux

Tags: scp

I have got an below error while executing the below command while placing a file in gatekeeper example server through a script.

```
scp -oHostKeyAlgorithms=+ssh-dss -i ~/.ssh/gatekeeper -P 18000 /var/applications/TEST_20190130.csv 74570-1@isdw-test.avc.db.com
```

The error is:

```
29/01/19,05:51:44 ** Start transfer to gatekeeper isdw-test.avc.db.com:
command-line line 0: Bad protocol 2 host key algorithms '+ssh-dss'.^M
lost connection
29/01/19,05:51:44 ** !!! File transfer to isdw-test.avc.db.com: Failed !!!
```

But, when I ran this command manually and able to place file in the server.

```
scp -oHostKeyAlgorithms=+ssh-dss -i ~/.ssh/gatekeeper -P 18000 /var/applications/TEST_20190130.csv 74570-1@isdw-test.avc.db.com
```

Answer (score 1):

The error is there in English `Bad protocol 2 host key algorithms '+ssh-dss'`. DSS is a protocol 1 specific algorithm, and modern SSH daemons/clients do not support protocol 1, it has been deprecated.

So, you have to take out -oHostKeyAlgorithms=+ssh-dss  from your command line key, it is not supported anymore.

Comment: If we do so, then we should require a new key right for the connection??

Comment: Wjhat happens if you try the command without he ssh-dss? any error?

Comment: The changed scp command worked...Thank you very much.

Comment: Be aware of following old recipes/pages, some things have changed in the last few years. Also, what I have told you in the comments is what the answer is saying...Please do not forget to mark it as correct.

Comment: ssh-dss is very definitely a protocol 2 pkalg (see rfc4253) and although OpenSSH 7.0 (2015-08) up remove it from the _default_ list you can still specify it. Is it possible the script got an old program version, perhaps by altering PATH? OpenSSH before 7.0 did not support the plus-sign syntax for `HostKeyAlgorithms` -- you had to spell out the full list. That said, I agree leaving out the option is usually good; the OpenSSH team are pretty cautious and their defaults safe.

Comment: In any case: You need to specify the destination path. Separate the host from the path with a colon like `....74570-1@isdw-test.avc.db.com:`. Otherwise the file gets copied into a local file `74570-1@isdw-test.avc.db.com`.